# Using sed to convert text file to a C string

Tags: c++, c, sed

I would like to use sed to replace newlines, tabs, quotes and backslashes in a text file to use it as char constant in C, but I'm lost at the start. It would be nice to maintain the newlines also in the output, adding a '\n', then a double quote to close the text line, a crlf, and another double quote to reopen the line, for example:

line1

line2

would become

"line1\n"

"line2\n"

Can anybody at least point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this as a `sed` command file:

```
s/\\/\\\\/g
s/"/\\"/g
s/  /\\t/g
s/^/"/
s/$/\\n"/
```

NB: there's an embedded tab in the third line, if using `vi` insert by pressing `^v <tab>`

1. `s/\\/\\\\/g`   - escape back slashes
2. `s/"/\\"/g`   - escape quotes
3. `s/ /\\t/g`   - convert tabs
4. `s/^/"/`   - prepend quote
5. `s/$/\\n"/`   - append \n and quote

Comment: Your solution is much better.

Comment: (3) should probably use \t instead of an embedded tab (easier to copy/paste). (4) and (5) should probably have /g on the end, otherwise they won't apply to all lines. Finally I would add (6) s/\r//g to strip Windows carriage returns (which mess things up). It works as requested for me with these changes.

Comment: [In this post](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/convert-text-file-to-a-c-string/) this answer was converted to a one-liner, which was very useful to me: `sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g;s/  /\\t/g;s/^/"/;s/$/\\n"/' $@`

Answer (score 1):

Better still:

```
'"'`printf %s "$your_text" | sed -n -e 'H;$!b' -e 'x;s/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g;s/    /\\t/g;s/^\n//;s/\n/\\n" \n "/g;p'`'"'
```

Unlike the one above, this handles newlines correctly as well. I'd just about call it a one-liner.

Answer (score -1):

In Perl, file input from stdin, out to stdout.  Hexifies, so no worries about escaping stuff. Doesn't remove tabs, etc. Output is a static C string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @c = <STDIN>;

print "static char* c_str = {\n";
foreach (@c) {
    my @s = split('');
    print qq(\t");
    printf("\\x%02x", ord($_)) foreach @s;
    print qq("\n);
}
print "};\n";
```